# In Laravel project, where do I put code which reads data from database tables, which would be common to multiple controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

***Background:***

I am having my first encounter with any MVC framework, as I am developing a little application with PHP web framework Laravel v6 and MongoDB (with jenssegers moloquent) as database engine. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q) tutorial series to learn Laravel 6.

Normally when I used to develop such applications with simple php, I would create one file called `readFromDb.php` and in it I would find/read/select data from all DB tables (collections in Mongodb). Then I would include in on top of every PHP file in which I would need to do some processing on any data from DB.

For example, if I have the following collections

1. allPaintingsCollection
2. paintingHistoriesCollection
3. paintingCategoriesCollection
4. artGalleriesCollection
5. paintingArtistsCollection
6. supervisorArtistsCollection
7. smPlatformsCollection
8. nonSmPlatformsCollection
9. targetSchoolsCollection

I would select all records/documents from them into associative arrays in the `readFromDb.php`, and then include `readFromDb.php` on top of every page where I would need to display or do processing on data from DB.

***Question:***

Now, in Laravel, should I create such a script called `readFromDb.php` and include it on top of every function in every single controller? In that case, where should I put this `readFromDb.php` file, and how do I *include* it in controllers?

Or should I write code to read from relevant DB collection/table in each function in every controller, before using that data from DB?

Comment: that "Collection" thing you was doing, in Laravel il called Eloquent Model, every model represent a table on your database, with it's property and relations, read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: @Berto99 SQL database tables map to NoSQL database Collections. Since I'm using Mongodb, so I am using the term Collection. I know that Eloquent Model is an interface on a db table/collection to simplify interation with that table/collection. My question is entirely something else, as you can see in the question. Thank you though.

Comment: there are other packages that add to eloquent the needs for mongodb https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: You can consider the repository design pattern for it. See this link https://cubettech.com/resources/blog/introduction-to-repository-design-pattern/

Comment: @Berto99 From the question: " Laravel v6 and MongoDB (with jenssegers moloquent)" - I am referring to the one you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

I am using class and call it as `repository` to handle all my request through database

First i create an file `UserRepository`

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Model\User;

class UserRepository
{
    function getUsers(){
       Return User::get();    
    }
}
```

Then in Controller, you just need to call the `repository` in the parent of `contruct`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;
    function __construct(){
        $this->user = new UserRepository();
    }

    function index(){
        $users = $this->user->getUsers(); // getUsers() is the function inside the repository class
        return view('user',compact('users'));
    }

}
```

That's how I do code in laravel, because i dont want to call `Laravel Model` and do all the store, reads  inside Controller and cause messy code

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) what presents [Object Relation Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) interface.

In Introduction:

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation **for working with your database**. Each database table has a corresponding *"Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.*

Basically, same as your `readFromDb.php` file but it handles with OOP so codebase is very  understandable and expandable and strictly related with your code.

When querying with Eloquent you use Models. If your query result has single row you get single [Model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), if your result has multiple rows you get [Eloquent\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections) result set contain your models.

Finally, you mustn't write ORM in Laravel because you already have.

If you think high level abstract accessors; you should explore design patterns. After that you can think to Repository Pattern, Decorator Pattern etc.